# unknown host exception while accessing graph.facebook.com

Tags: facebook-graph-api, json.net, facebook-java-api

I'm getting an java.net.unknownhostexception while accessing the URL but i'm able to access through browser.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException`enter code here`
{
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/?
access_token=xxxxx&fields=name,likes,posts");
System.out.println(json.toString());
System.out.println(json.get("likes"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The request URL you're using is not valid. In your request URL, change `page_id` to the actual Facebook page id you are trying to request data for, and include the API version you are working with.

E.g. if I wanted to access a page with the id 3454546 -

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/3454546?access_token=xxxxx&fields=name,likes,posts`